# Difficulty to create a function groupby in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe y :

```
y.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 17 columns):
TIMESTAMP                       5 non-null datetime64[ns]
P_ACT_KW                        5 non-null int64
PERIODE_TARIF                   5 non-null object
P_SOUSCR                        5 non-null int64
high_energy                     5 non-null int64
medium_energy                   5 non-null int64
low_energy                      5 non-null int64
0ACT_TIME_ETA_PRG_P2REF_RM      5 non-null int64
0ACT_TIME_ETA_PRG_VDES_RM       5 non-null int64
0ACT_TIME_ETA_PRG_P3REF_RM      5 non-null int64
0ACT_TIME_ETA_POMP_RECIRC_N1    5 non-null int64
0ACT_TIME_ETA_POMP_RECIRC_N2    5 non-null int64
0ACT_TIME_ETA_POMP_RECIRC_N3    5 non-null int64
0ACT_TIME_ETA_SURPRES_AIR_N1    5 non-null int64
0ACT_TIME_ETA_SURPRES_AIR_N2    5 non-null int64
0ACT_TIME_ETA_SURPRES_AIR_N3    5 non-null int64
class_energy                    5 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(14), object(2)
memory usage: 720.0+ bytes 

TIMESTAMP P_ACT_KW PERIODE_TARIF P_SOUSCR high_energy medium_energy low_energy 0ACT_TIME_ETA_PRG_P2REF_RM 0ACT_TIME_ETA_PRG_VDES_RM 0ACT_TIME_ETA_PRG_P3REF_RM 0ACT_TIME_ETA_POMP_RECIRC_N1 0ACT_TIME_ETA_POMP_RECIRC_N2 0ACT_TIME_ETA_POMP_RECIRC_N3 0ACT_TIME_ETA_SURPRES_AIR_N1 0ACT_TIME_ETA_SURPRES_AIR_N2 0ACT_TIME_ETA_SURPRES_AIR_N3 class_energy
2016-05-10 04:30:00 107 HP 250 0 107 0 100 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 medium
2016-05-10 04:40:00 109 HP 250 0 109 0 0 0 100 0 0 0 0 0 0 medium
2016-05-10 04:50:00 106 HP 250 0 106 0 0 0 100 0 3 0 0 0 0 high
```

I try to create a fucntion which calculate the sum of columns group by the column 'class_energy ', For this I did like this :

```
def sum_proba(data):
    data = (data.groupby(by='class_energy', as_index=False)['0ACT_TIME_ETA_PRG_P2REF_RM', '0ACT_TIME_ETA_PRG_VDES_RM','0ACT_TIME_ETA_PRG_P3REF_RM','0ACT_TIME_ETA_POMP_RECIRC_N1','0ACT_TIME_ETA_POMP_RECIRC_N2', '0ACT_TIME_ETA_POMP_RECIRC_N3','0ACT_TIME_ETA_SURPRES_AIR_N1'], data['0ACT_TIME_ETA_SURPRES_AIR_N2','0ACT_TIME_ETA_SURPRES_AIR_N3'].sum())
    return data
```

When I test, I get this error :

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py
> ```
>
> in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
>          1944             try:
>       -> 1945                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
>          1946             except KeyError:
>
> ```
> pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4154)()
>
> pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4018)()
>
> pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
> ```
>
> (pandas\hashtable.c:12368)()
>
> ```
> pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
> ```
>
> (pandas\hashtable.c:12322)()
>
> ```
> KeyError: ('0ACT_TIME_ETA_SURPRES_AIR_N2', '0ACT_TIME_ETA_SURPRES_AIR_N3')
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-115-6f698f306092> in <module>()
> ----> 1 sum_proba(x)
>
> <ipython-input-114-a946896b0480> in sum_proba(data)
>       1 def sum_proba(data):
> ----> 2     data = (data.groupby(by='class_energy', as_index=False)['0ACT_TIME_ETA_PRG_P2REF_RM',
> ```
>
> '0ACT_TIME_ETA_PRG_VDES_RM','0ACT_TIME_ETA_PRG_P3REF_RM','0ACT_TIME_ETA_POMP_RECIRC_N1','0ACT_TIME_ETA_POMP_RECIRC_N2',
>   '0ACT_TIME_ETA_POMP_RECIRC_N3','0ACT_TIME_ETA_SURPRES_AIR_N1'],
>   data['0ACT_TIME_ETA_SURPRES_AIR_N2','0ACT_TIME_ETA_SURPRES_AIR_N3'].sum())
>             3     return data
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py
> ```
>
> in **getitem**(self, key)
>          1995             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
>          1996         else:
>       -> 1997             return self._getitem_column(key)
>          1998 
>          1999     def _getitem_column(self, key):
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py
> ```
>
> in _getitem_column(self, key)
>          2002         # get column
>          2003         if self.columns.is_unique:
>       -> 2004             return self._get_item_cache(key)
>          2005 
>          2006         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py
> ```
>
> in _get_item_cache(self, item)
>          1348         res = cache.get(item)
>          1349         if res is None:
>       -> 1350             values = self._data.get(item)
>          1351             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
>          1352             cache[item] = res
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py
> ```
>
> in get(self, item, fastpath)
>          3288 
>          3289             if not isnull(item):
>       -> 3290                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
>          3291             else:
>          3292                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isnull(self.items)]
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py
> ```
>
> in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
>          1945                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
>          1946             except KeyError:
>       -> 1947                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
>          1948 
>          1949         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
>
> ```
> pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4154)()
>
> pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4018)()
>
> pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
> ```
>
> (pandas\hashtable.c:12368)()
>
> ```
> pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
> ```
>
> (pandas\hashtable.c:12322)()
>
> ```
> KeyError: ('0ACT_TIME_ETA_SURPRES_AIR_N2', '0ACT_TIME_ETA_SURPRES_AIR_N3')
> ```

ANy idea to help me to resolve this problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: are you sure that you have **.sum()** at the end of **data = ...** ?     Also seems there's an extra space before **.sum()**

Comment: @grubjesic thank you, I edit my post . kind regards

Comment: seems **y** data frame is not big so it will be useful to share that sample

Comment: It' s done I edit my post

Comment: Try: `data.groupby(by='class_energy', as_index=False)[[col for col in list(data) if col.startswith('0ACT')]].sum()`

Comment: @NickilMaveli great man!! It works fine!! Many thanks :)